# Discord bot won't reply to commands with contents like this "KlH04s69"

Tags: node.js, discord

This is not a big issue for me, i'm just curious why bot replies to this command without any problems

```
else if (command === "give me cookies") {
    const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('./laisaembarasment.png');
    message.reply(`NOPE`);
    message.channel.send(attachment);
}
```

Yet bot do not replies to this

```
else if (command === "KlH04s69") {
    const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('./hornyticket.png');
    message.reply(`just used his ticket! Oh no, it's a horny one...`);
    message.channel.send(attachment);
}
```

Comment: The error seems to be rooted somewhere else. Could you provide an error log?

Answer (score -1):

I cannot reply to it since everything in the command input has to be lowercase, hence

`const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();`

Comment: And if @Yanzihko would provide his/her declaration for `command`, the problem would be solved very quickly and easily.